# Как создать горизонтальную линейку с квадратными зигзагами?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-shapes

Можете ли вы помочь мне с этим `hr-style`, таким как `zip`, только в css.
Я даже не знаю, с чего начать, конечно, я догадываюсь, что мне нужно использовать 2 градиента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to create a horizontal rule with square zig zags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67049229/7394871) от участника  [@Caragea Theodor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15606426/caragea-theodor).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67049229/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант SVG:

```html
<svg width="600" height="38">

<line x1="0" y1="20" x2="600" y2="20" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="6 6" />
<line x1="0" y1="26" x2="600" y2="26" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" />
<line x1="6" y1="32" x2="600" y2="32" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="6 6" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Как относишься к мелким `вредным` советам? Не напрягает? Если в   stroke-dasharray="6 6" параметры одинаковые, то можно только один параметр указывать `stroke-dasharray="6"`

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте как показано ниже:

```css
.box {
  height:15px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,blue  0 5px,#0000 0 10px) top,    /* top gradient*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0 5px,blue  0 10px) bottom, /* bottom  gradient*/ 
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) center; /* линия посередине */
  background-size:100% calc(100%/3); /* 3 одинаковых размера */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

или

```css
.box {
  height:15px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,blue  0 5px,#0000 0 10px) top,   
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0 5px,blue  0 10px) bottom;
  background-size:100% calc(2*100%/3); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Еще одна упрощенная версия

```css
.box {
  height:15px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,black  50%,#0000 0) top,   
    linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 50%,black  0) bottom;
  background-size:10px calc(2*100%/3);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67049319/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>